# Why is Firefox scrolling faster with Nouveau driver than with Nvidia driver?

Tags: nvidia, nouveau

I'm really astonished that using the nvidia driver results in poor speed and high cpu usage when working with Unity. I mean scrolling in Firefox consumes 100% cpu time and still isn't as fluid as it should be. Nouveau is much better, but still far from being great.
I tried the latest 310.14 beta and also all other versions of the nvidia drivers offered by jockey.

Can I do something about this? I would really love scrolling in Firefox without my fan making a lot of noise...

Answer (score 0):

In my case using the proprietary driver for nvidia, in a macbook with Natty, was much better than using the default drivers. After installing Natty, scrolling and switching windows was so slow that I was thinking about uninstalling Ubuntu. The experience improved when I used the nouveau driver in a newer release live-cd, but since nobody answered how could I switch to use that driver, I changed to the proprietary drivers with menu: System>Administration>Additional_drivers